# Giving Elements an other structure than a box for example a triangle

Tags: html, css, image

I have a box with 3 triangles inside. 
The 3 triangles should be a link, but they are clickable boxes and not triangles, so if you click on one image it depends which link is the destination.

If you click on the left image the destination should be link 1 but it is link3 because of the box from the bottom-pic.

The position of the elements is good. But the link should be the same size like the images and not just a box with the same width and height.
I have tried overflow:hidden and z-index, but it didnt worked.

```
<style>
#card{
  width:472px;
  height:472px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
}
#l3{
  position:relative;
  bottom:149px;
}
</style>

<div id="card">
    <a href="link1.html" >
      <img src="img/left.png">
    </a>
    <a href="link2.html">
      <img src="img/right.png">
    </a>
    <a href="link3.html" id="l3">
      <img src="img/bottom.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the anchor link being the same size as the image. 
Or the image being an real triangle and not a box.

Thank you, and if you have questions feel free to ask.

Screenshot of Card:
https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5488/ap538p4i_png.htm

Comment: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `clip-path` to do this if you want to restrict the mouse events to only the visible area:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
}
.box > a {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}

.box > a:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0,50% 0, 50% 50%, 0 70%);
    clip-path:polygon(0 0,50% 0, 50% 50%, 0 70%);
}
.box > a:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(100% 0,50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 70%);
    clip-path:polygon(100% 0,50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 70%);
}

.box > a:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 100%,0 70%, 50% 50%, 100% 70%,100% 100%);
    clip-path:polygon(0 100%,0 70%, 50% 50%, 100% 70%,100% 100%);
}
.box > a:hover {
   filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/800/400)"></a>
</div>
```

[image: clip images]

A simplified version where you need clip-path with only one element:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
}
.box > a {
  position:absolute;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}

.box > a:nth-child(1) {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  bottom:30%;
}
.box > a:nth-child(2) {
   top:0;
  right:0;
  left:50%;
  bottom:30%;
}

.box > a:nth-child(3) {
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,0 30%, 50% 0%, 100% 30%,100% 100%);
}
.box > a:hover {
   filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/800/400)"></a>
</div>
```

Another idea without clip-path:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box > a {
  position:absolute;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box > a:nth-child(1) {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  bottom:30%;
  background-size:0;    
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
.box > a:nth-child(2) {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:50%;
  bottom:30%;
  background-size:0;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.box > a:nth-child(1):before,
.box > a:nth-child(2):before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:inherit;
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
.box > a:nth-child(1):before {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}

.box > a:nth-child(2):before {
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
}

.box > a:nth-child(3) {
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.box > a:hover {
   filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/400)" ></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/800/400)"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Very helpful! Exactly what i asked for. Any idea how I can change the title or something else so other users with the same problem can find the article faster?

Comment: @klediooo the title looks good to me, you can probably try to put your initial code inside a snippet like I did in my answer so we can better see your code then my answer to understand .. also don't forget to accept the answer if it solve your issue ;)